# How to use FindStr with special characters?

Tags: batch-file, find, findstr

I need to find the word `="HQDFSQL"/>` using the `FindStr` command in a batch script.
What query should I use to accomplish this?

Comment: In general, special characters can be escaped on the command line by prefixing them with **ctrl-V**, which will appear on the screen as `^V`.

Comment: Enter `FindStr /?` at the Command Prompt and read the usage information. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] before [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51656320/edit) to include a [mcve] of the batch file content you have tried along with what was returned.

Comment: Under the regular expression reference for the `FINDSTR` help file, it says `\\` is the escape character.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - What command line are you using? I've only seen control characters appear like that in Linux.

Comment: As a side note, have you considered the `Find` command as an alternative?

Comment: @SomethingDark - Windows command prompt, which is where the tag [tag:batch-file] applies to.

Comment: @Squashman - and  the backslash will itself have to be escaped (with `^V`) on the command line because it's a special character to Windows.

Comment: `findstr "=\"HQDFSQL\"/>"`?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - I am aware that [batch-file] is applicable to Windows (it's the only tag I look at), but I've got a command prompt open and I'm pressing CTRL+V and nothing is happening.

Comment: Oh wait, I needed to use legacy mode

Comment: Thank you @aschipfl , the command worked !!!!